# ORA-01427 Subquery returns more then one row..Oracle Update Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you write a update statement with a Sub-Select in an Oracle Environment (SQL Developer)?

Example: UPDATE table SET column = (SELECT....)

Every time I try this it gives me ORA-01427 "Sub select returns more then one row" even if there is no WHERE clause..

Comment: Easy, just make sure that your query only return a single record.  Post the full query for better results here.

Comment: Can you not update multiple rows at a time..? say if I had 100,000 records that were 1's and i needed them to be 0's can I not do that in oracle with a simple update?  or can I only update 1 row?

Comment: Yes, you can.  I meant that each record which is being updated must generate a subquery also returning one record.  You need a correlated subquery here.

Comment: finally got it.. Thank you for your help! Looked up  correlated sub query and found an example that worked with my current situation!.. Thanks very much been working on it for almost a week now and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: @JJ1567424 How do you expect us to help you if all you give is `SELECT ...`????????

Answer (score 1):

Based on the understanding of your question I'd suggest use Merge statement.

```
Merge into Table1
Using
(SELECT * from table2 where condition) Temp
On (Table1.columname condition Temp.columname)
When matched Then update Set Table1.column_name = Temp.column_name;
```

Table1 is the table where you want to update the records.
Table2 is the table from which you want to get the data (The sub query which you are talking about )
Using this merge statement you will be able to update n number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update multiple rows, you can either use a `MERGE` statement (as in @jackkds7's answer above) or you can use a filter on your subselect:

```
UPDATE table t1
   SET column = ( SELECT column FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.key = t1.key );
```

If there aren't matches in `table2` for all the records in `table` then `column` will be set to `NULL` for the non-matches. To avoid that, add a `WHERE EXISTS` clause:

```
UPDATE table t1
   SET column = ( SELECT column FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.key = t1.key )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.key = t1.key );
```

Oh and in the event that `key` is not unique for `table2`, you can aggregate (up to you to figure out which function would be best):

```
UPDATE table t1
   SET column = ( SELECT MAX(column) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.key = t1.key )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.key = t1.key );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help if you posted your actual query.
In essence, the "inner" select would be executed for each row that would be updated. This inner select query is called a correlated subquery:

```
    UPDATE table t SET t.column = (
        select ot.othercolumn  from othertable ot 
        where ot.fk = t.id  --This is the correlation part, that finds 
        --he right value for the row you are currently updating
     )
```

You must ensure the subquery you use will always return just a single row and a single column for every time it runs (that is, for every row that is going to be updated). If needed, you can use MAX(), or ROWNUM to ensure you always only get 1 value

More examples:
[Using Correlated Subqueries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)